# Skip elements when counting in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to create mutiple `Arraylist<Integer>` from a range of `int`, but when I try to skip some elements everything is messed up. I split the numbers in 5 different `ArrayList<>` and in paralel trying to put all in a common `Arraylist<>`. Until the first skip I get series like :

```
Rain    Snow    Cloudy    Sunshine
 1        2        3          4
Rain    Snow    Cloudy    Sunshine
 5        6        7          8
```

and after skiping the day number 29 :

```
Rain    Cloudy   Sunshine    Rain
 30      31        32         34

Rain    Cloudy   Sunshine    Rain
 34       35       36         38
```

This is my code bellow :

```
private List<Day> getCompleteDayList(){
        ArrayList<Integer> sunshineArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> rainArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> cloudyArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> snowArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> fogArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> dayNumbersList = new ArrayList<>();
        mDayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Day currentDay = null;
        int dayNumber = 0;
        int dayImage = 0;
        for (int i=1;i<=4;i++){
            for (int k=i;k<=87;k+=4){
                dayNumber = k;
                    if (i==1){
                        if (k==29){ // trying to skip 29
                            fogArray.add(k);
                            k = 30;// and begin counting from 30
                        }else if (k==58){//trying to skip 58
                            fogArray.add(k);
                            k=59;//and begin counting from 59
                        }else if (k==87){
                            fogArray.add(k);
                        }
                        rainArray.add(k);
                    }else if (i==2){
                        snowArray.add(k);
                    }else if (i==3){
                        cloudysArray.add(k);
                    }else {
                        sunshineArray.add(k);
                    }
                dayNumbersList.add(dayNumber);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(dayNumbers);
        int currentDayNumber = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i < dayNumbers.size();i++){
            currentDayNumber = dayNumbers.get(i);
            if (rainArray.contains(currentDayNumber)){
                dayImage = R.drawable.rain;
            }else if (snowArray.contains(currentDayNumber)){
                dayImage = R.drawable.snow;
            }else if (cloudyArray.contains(currentDayNumber)){
                dayImage = R.drawable.clouds;
            }else if (sunshineArray.contains(currentDayNumber)){
                dayImage = R.drawable.sunshine;
            }else if (fogArray.contains(currentDayNumber)){
                dayImage = R.drawable.rsz_water;
            }
            currentDay = new Day(currentDayNumber,dayImage);
            mDayList.add(currentDay);
        }
        return mDayList;
    }
```

I want the series to remain like before skiping and every 29th day to be fogDay, all of this I display into an Recyclerview.

Thanks !!!

Comment: and what is your actual problem?

Comment: my Snow day it doesn't appear anymore after I make the first skip and the Rain day is doubled in the serie.

Comment: Can you please explain what your code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the first iteration. You are incrementing the day(k) by one, therefore you will actually skip some days (e.g. the gap between 32 and 34) and having a doubled days afterwards (32, 34, 34). (Because you go from 25 to 30 to 34, 33 will never get assigned). You have to increment the day(k) in the other i-iterations too

You are not imcrementing the value of `k` when `i!=1`, thus you have rain days:
1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 30, 34.
Snow days:
2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34.

And because you are calling `if (rainArray.contains(currentDayNumber))`

before `else if (snowArray.contains(currentDayNumber))`, you will set a rain day instead of a snow day.

Try showing the output of the lists (e.g. rainArray and snowArray) and you see the issue.
Try: `rainArray.stream().forEach(System.out::println)`, likewise with snowArray.

If you replace the `else if` with an `if` you see that they are still there.

EDIT: Here is a working example in one array with the help of modulo as your example may get too complicated considering the bug. It may help you to get new ideas:

```
private List<Day> getCompleteDayList() {
  // Temporary save days as (in my case) Strings
  final List<String> rawDays = new ArrayList<>();
  // The foggy days
  final List<Integer> fogDays = Arrays.asList(29, 58, 87);

  final int NUMBER_OF_DAYS = 100;
  // When following a certain pattern, create it first
  for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_DAYS; ++i) {
     switch (i % 4) {
     case 1:
        rawDays.add("rain");
        break;
     case 2:
        rawDays.add("snow");
        break;
     case 3:
        rawDays.add("cloudy");
        break;
     case 0:
        rawDays.add("sunshine");
        break;
     }
  }

  // Add a fog string in the list. If you want to replace, you may try to rawDays.set(...)
  fogDays.stream().forEach(dayNumber -> rawDays.add(dayNumber - 1, "fog"));

  final List<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();

  // Add the days
  int dayIndex = 1;
  for (final String weather : rawDays) {
     days.add(new Day(dayIndex++, weather));
     if (days.size() >= NUMBER_OF_DAYS) {
        break;
     }
  }
  return days;
}
```